Configuration HDFS, SPARK, ZEPPELIN
Project-structure:
ROOT:
- hadoop
  - conf
    - core-site.xml
    - hdfs-site.xml
- local
  - data
    - .csv files
- zeppelin
  - conf
    - files .json
  - notebook
- docker-compose

core-site.xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode:8020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
        <value>hdfs-cluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.hdfs-cluster</name>
        <value>namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hdfs-cluster.namenode</name>
        <value>namenode:8020</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

hdfs-site.xml:
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///hadoop/dfs/name</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///hadoop/dfs/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

docker-compose:
version: '3'

services:
  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:3.1.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
      - HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
    volumes:
      - spark_volume:/spark
      - ./hadoop/conf:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop

  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.1.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
      - namenode
      - datanode
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - "SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2"
      - "SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4g"
      - HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
    volumes:
      - spark_volume:/spark
      - ./hadoop/conf:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop

  zeppelin:
    image: apache/zeppelin:0.10.1
    container_name: zeppelin
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
      - namenode
      - datanode
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./zeppelin/notebook:/opt/zeppelin/notebook
      - ./zeppelin/conf:/opt/zeppelin/conf
      - spark_volume:/opt/zeppelin/spark
      - ./data:/opt/zeppelin/data
      - ./hadoop/conf:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
    environment:
      - "SPARK_HOME=/opt/zeppelin/spark"
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop

  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    container_name: namenode
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    ports:
      - "50070:50070"
      - "8020:8020"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
      - ./hadoop/conf:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
      - ./local/data:/hadoop/data  # Mount local data directory

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    container_name: datanode
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    ports:
      - "50075:50075"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
      - ./hadoop/conf:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop

volumes:
  spark_volume:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:


The problem is that namenode does not see the configuration files, the same with datanode. As long as these files are visible in the namenode container. The .csv files are visible in the containers, but you can't copy them using hadoop fs -put /hadoop/data/my_file.csv /path/to/my_file.csv.
datanode after running the containers constantly returns this message:
datanode | 24/06/18 09:26:45 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec190a2b6055/172.24.0.3:8020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

when trying to copy files using ** hadoop dfs** i get these messages:
24/06/18 09:24:42 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /path/to/ratings.csv.COPYING could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3045)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:493)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2217)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2213)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2213)

The general idea is to distribute .CSV files and they should be accessible from within Hadoop
The best part is that namenode:
http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview

returns SUMMARY:
Summary
Security is off.

Safemode is off.

8 files and directories, 0 blocks = 8 total filesystem object(s).

Heap Memory used 111.09 MB of 204.5 MB Heap Memory. Max Heap Memory is 889 MB.

Non Heap Memory used 35.7 MB of 36.44 MB Committed Non Heap Memory. Max Non Heap Memory is -1 B.

in ZEPPELIN:
%pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable

And such file imports:
%pyspark
infile2 = "hdfs://namenode:8020/hadoop/data/ratings.csv"
lines = spark.read.csv(infile2, header=True)
lines.show()

I get errors like this:
AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://namenode:8020/hadoop/data/ratings.csv

However, the file itself at
/hadoop/data

i see this .csv files :/
I would also add that by running the container
docker exec -it spark-master /bin/bash

and typing:
/spark/bin/pyspark --master spark://spark-master:7077

SPARK starts up and simple commands in ZEPPELIN work correctly
I took the whole configuration together from here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/dockerizing-apache-zeppelin-and-apache-spark-for-easy-deployment-1814d0c1c245

and it generally works, despite serving files. Do you have any ideas why it won't work properly? What could be the cause of this?

Once you enter the container are the files there? Also /etc/hosts should have an entry for namenode in the Datanode.
